# Errors with: https://graph.facebook.com/app_id/insights/share_views/day?access_token=

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get the number of users who have seen pages shared from my site using: https://graph.facebook.com/app_id/insights/share_views/day?access_token=

I am filling in my app_id and access_token and I am getting an error response of:
Array ( [error] => Array ( [type] => OAuthException [message] => (#604) Invalid metric name: share_views ) )

Has anyone run into this error and determined the cause?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to actually specify time period you are trying to access.  For an example of an application that is working and can access Insight data, check here https://github.com/facebook/insights-api-sample.

Notice that they specify a since and until post parameter in this file:
https://github.com/facebook/insights-api-sample/blob/master/php/results.php

Comment: I based my code off of that sample, I just copied the get_insights function and created a get_share_views function. The only thing I changed was line 38: $path = $id . '/insights'; To $path = $id . '/insights/share_views/day';